# How to allow noip2 access through iptables with drop policy

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a server which has `iptable` set to input/output policy drop. I only allow basic connections to services like Apache2 and SSH from outside the machine. The machine is only allowed to access websites which are required to function properly (e.g. `apt-get` updates).
I however have issue trying to allow `noip2` to access internet through `iptables` - every time the update fails. Currently I was only able to make it work if I set all policies to accept, however it is important for me to keep my server with drop policies.

Is there a way to allow noip2 to update via iptables? I have tried to find anything online, but nothing that I have found have helped me in any way.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 if this helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Figure out what specifically is needed for *noip2*.
2. Allow *that* in your firewall.

So, one way of figuring out what's needed (if the documentation doesn't say) is to enable **logging** of dropped packets. Then you can run noip2, look at the logs, and find that it's trying to access server X on port Y.

If you drop packets only via chain policy, just add this rule at the end:

```
-A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "dropped: "
```

Then the kernel log (`dmesg`) will start collecting information about packets which reached that rule – i.e. those which didn't hit any previous accept/reject/drop rules. Use that information to write accept rules for noip2.

Note: If writing IP-based rules, don't forget to check whether the address looks like it might belong to a CDN like Cloudflare. In that case, whitelisting just that single address won't last long and you'll need other methods (such as a filtering proxy, or rules based on the UID/GID of the noip2 program).